# Autowring datasource and jdbcTemplate returning NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jpa, yaml, datasource

> I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I am unable to figure it out.
>   I am trying to build datasource and jdbcTemplate from a yaml file but
>   it seems to be returning NullPointerException.  So I want to use the
>   datasource I configured in yams file. The spa configuration is being
>   picked up, but the datasource is not.
>
> The Exception I am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mypackage.Data.getResult(DemoProject.java:95)
        at com.mypackage.controller.DemoController.getSampleData(DemoController.java:122)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
```

> *Repository*

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public class DataRepo {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("postgresDataSource")
    DataSource postgresDS;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("postgresJdbcTemplate")
    JdbcTemplate postgresjdbcTemplate;

    private final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_person";

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize(){
        setDataSource(postgresDS);
        setJdbcTemplate(postgresjdbcTemplate);
    }

    public void getResult() {
        try {
            postgresjdbcTemplate.update(SELECT_SQL);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> DbConfig

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties postgresDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "postgresDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        return postgresDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "postgresJdbcTemplate")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public JdbcTemplate postgresJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("postgresDataSource") DataSource dsPostgres) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsPostgres);
    }
}
```

> application-dev.yml

```
# Spring Boot configuration
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  # Database
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
    username: user
    password: password
    platform: postgres
  # JPA properties
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    open-in-view: false
    generate-ddl: false
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Demo Project</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Please post your pom or gradle

Comment: I have updated my post with the pom.xml

Comment: Try to remove the H2 dependency from your pom file or apply the following on your SpringBoot runner class* @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) . *The class annotated with @springbootApplication

Comment: I removed h2 dependency and I still got the same exception

Comment: Remove @Primary for other two data sources, leave primary only one

Comment: I only have one datasource. However, I removed it just to check and still the same issue